# Isolate Specific Text/Number combination and paste it in a new cell

Tags: excel, find, vba

Hi I'm new to Stackoverflow and to VBA in general.

I have a large set of data in column [Description] of my table1.
I have been trying to find a way to select specific data from this column and paste this specific data into another column of my table1.

For example, in the [Description] column I have some text and an Invoice number ex:FT022154. This data varies, sometimes two or three invoice numbers are there and sometimes none.
I wanted to isolate those invoice numbers and then copy and paste these  into another column of table1.

I honestly don't know where to start and can't find anything specifically related to my issue.

EDIT 1 (Image added)
[Table 1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VWlo.png)

So basically, I don't need to split the informations in the Description column, just copy the needed info and past it in the invoice column.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is table1 an actual table object or a worksheet name? You only want to copy the non-empty cells - and the whole cell text, correct? What columns are decription and the copy-to columns?

Comment: I added an image to better visualize my issue

Comment: Please edit your question narrative, it is totally different from the image you have uploaded now. So my posted answer becomes invalid and hence deleted.

Comment: I may correct my previous comments as per following. You should have uploaded Table 1 Screenshot in the Ist Instance itself. Understanding your requirements as per description led to my posted answer invalid and hence deleted.

Comment: What is the Identifier for invoices in the mixed text description field and is expected to remain same for example do all invoices start with "FT"

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't formulated properly, all invoices start with FT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below works for me. Copy it into a new module and change Sheetname and columns to fit your workbook. In my code, Column C is Description, and Column A is Invoices. You may also need to redefine `fr` (firstrow), which is now set to 2.

```
Sub invoiceSeparation()


Dim tws As Worksheet

Dim description() As String

Dim fr, lr As Integer           'first row, last row of data



    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InvoiceSeparation")

    fr = 2

    lr = tws.Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Row

    With tws

        .Range("A" & fr & ":A" & lr).ClearContents

        For r = fr To lr

            description() = Split(.Range("C" & r).Value, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)

            For i = LBound(description) To UBound(description)

                If Left(description(i), 2) = "FT" Then

                    If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & r).Value) Then

                        .Range("A" & r).Value = .Range("A" & r).Value & " " & description(i)

                    Else

                        .Range("A" & r).Value = .Range("A" & r).Value & description(i)

                    End If

                End If

            Next i

        Next r

    End With


End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions on how this code works!

Comment: Great, thank you! Is it possible to also add a line of code that prevents the the macro to copy multiple times in the cell if ran multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I have added this line: `.Range("A" & fr & ":A" & lr).ClearContents`. What it does is to first clear your invoice column, so each run starts from scratch and updates everything to the latest state.

Comment: I'm comming back at you for this code! I'm working with 2 tables now, so I can't run this macro for the whole sheet. I would like to run it secifically for my new table ("Table2")... but I noticed that I have to use new denominations. I can't use this line for instance : `lr = tws.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns(16).End(xlUp).Row` 
Also, I guess I need to change the columns names as we are using a table:
Ex: From `Split(.Range("C" & r).Value, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)`
To
`Split(.Range("Table2[Description 3]" & r).Value, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)`
But all this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: where is your table2? example, if the description column of table2 is in column X, just change C to X.